# What is the normal flow for oAuth2 Google API for Server Applications

Tags: google-authentication, google-prediction

I am writing a simple Google API application that will help the user with some tasks using the Google Prediction API.

I am intending to use the API from a Server-Server perspective, so I am really not requesting data from the end-user.

Everywhere I read about the Google oAuth API even for Server-Server it tries to authenticate the enduser, but why? I (the application) want to access the API and be charged for it, not the end user. I don't want to know anything about the user...

So how do I get to consume the Google Prediction API without doing a user side oauth request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read [this one](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount)? I didn't find there are need for authentication of end user.

> If you use the Google Prediction API to act on behalf of your application without accessing any user data, your application uses its service-account credentials to prove its own identity, and no end user is involved.